# Pinterest: Can I access the main feed without using OAuth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, pinterest

I'm trying to get access to information for the main feed in Pinterest so that I can extract the link URLs and use them as part of a study on social engagement on the web that I am doing.

I know that it is possible to access an rss of a particular user with pinterest.com/user/pin-board/rss however I have not been able to find a way to gain access to the main page with the stream of new pins and this is even restricted so that you must specify individual boards that the user has.

I am currently working to get the information I am looking for via registration of an app to get me the access token I need but it would be much better if I could find a way that didn't require such a long winded approach.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: this stack overflow question has the latest info concerning pinterest api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation