# pinterest api documentation

Tags: json, api, mobile, documentation, pinterest

**Update Aug 2015:** Pinterest provides it here now https://dev.pinterest.com/

**Is there official or unofficial documentation on the v2 Pinterest API?**

Things I know:

- JSON api is in version 2.  https://api.pinterest.com/v2 gives you a json response
- People are programming against it because there is a mobile app and beta dev
- [Pintrest authentication question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333434/pinterest-authentication-url-returning-404-error/9333486#9333486)
- [PHP wrapper for v1 with updates for v2 on Github by Kellan](https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php) with methods: upload, pin, repin, boards, activity, popular  - reading Kellan's code is the best information I could find
- [More info](http://laughingmeme.org/2011/12/04/pinterest-api-php/) on Kellan's work with responses from Pinterest team
- [Private unofficial Facebook Pinterest Dev group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/pinterestapi/)
- [Here are some of the stars behind Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/about/team)

**Update Mar 4 2014**
Pinterest has unveiled a beta v3 API which you can request access to. Scroll down the page and you'll see the endpoints listed in the left column.
https://developers.pinterest.com/api_docs/

**Update Jan 9 2013**
Since https://api.pinterest.com/v2 gives a 404, it seems to have been moved to v3.
https://api.pinterest.com/v3

```
{ "status": "failure", "code": 11, "host": "053", "generated_at": "Wed, 09 Jan 2013 10:25:27 +0000", "message": "API method not found.", "data": null }
```

**Update Nov 19, 2012**
The unofficial api documentation at http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api is gone, along with their entire website.  I'm leaving the link in this post because it may come back online.  Still no word from Pinterest to developers on their api status.

**Update May 22, 2012**
Pinterest has still not provided a public api.  People are connecting to the api endpoints as the iPhone user agent, which is available to the iOS app

**Update Apr 17, 2012**
Thanks to tijn, we have [unofficial version 1(now v2) Pinterest api docs](http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api), and reports that only read endpoints are currently available so RSS style feeds are possible within rate limits.

**Update Apr 3, 2012**
The unofficial Facebook group has some quality info on it and several people asking questions and posting fairly useful responses

Comment: That's a good tip on the iPhone endpoint. I hadn't heard about that.

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits thanks for the heads up on tjin's website going down

Comment: any updates? seems this has gone stale :x

Comment: @ChuckKelly Pinterest has been silent about public development.  My hunch is that they are nurturing a private, albeit quiet, third party developer network.  There are a lifeless blog http://engineering.pinterest.com/ and Github account https://github.com/pinterest collecting dust.

Comment: Even among the unofficial ones and the older one I see only possibility to work on or get data for the logged in user. I wanted to do something like a keyword search :( for such a seemingly up and coming social platform I find this very irregular. Stats show me that the traffic from pinterest far exceeds twitter and I'm always tweeting..something to be learned here !

Comment: request api access here: https://developers.pinterest.com/api_request/

Comment: @JPHellemons thanks, just made another request but haven't had a response in the past.

Comment: The link that you provide for the pins: https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/[username]/[board_name]/pins/ does only retrieve a few pins, do you know if there is any way to specify an offset? I tried w/o the API, but there is a "bookmarks" parameter used to retrieve each page and I have no idea about how to generate it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure @Trylks

Comment: Right now api documentation shows "none" everywhere. Is the api still working?

Comment: @nicowernli no problems for me

Comment: Any update regarding May 2018, many users facing Token Generation error now, I am also.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is [no Official API Docs](https://support.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api) available for Pinterest as of today.

But there is the unofficial documentation for v2 here: http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api

Comment: Glad to see tijn updated it for v2, thanks

Comment: +1 Against @MikeGrace

Comment: @EncorePTL, I tried the curl requests listed http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api but everything returns 404 for me, are all of these disabled?

Comment: tijn.bo.lt is a dead link.

Comment: you can still get it on internet archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130308101718/http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api

Comment: any jar file for pintrest

Comment: links not working

Comment: both links not working anymore.

Answer (score 65):

I want to offer an update on the current status of the Pinterest API.

There is still no public API available. Pinterest also does not seem to be approving anyone who applies for access on their site.

As of right now, the endpoints of the Pinterest v3 API are almost complete although there is no official documentation. Below is a brief list of the types of endpoints that are available:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/users/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/search/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/domains/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/categories/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/boards/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pins/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/batch/
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/login/
```

You may discover many sub-endpoints to each of the endpoint above. I do have a list of many available endpoints, but since they're not public, I'm not going to post them here (Hint: Most of them are easy to guess). All of the above endpoints require an access_token parameter except for the login endpoint.

To generate a valid access_token, the developer will need to be granted access to the API by Pinterest which we all know is currently almost impossible.

Another option is to write a script to simulate a log in action to the `/v3/login` endpoint with your Pinterest username and password. It will return an access_token if request is successful. I'm not going into details about how this is done, as this is never meant to be part of the public API and is meant only for users logging into Pinterest on their mobile app.

However, you can generate access token for your Pinterest account for existing apps that have been approved by Pinterest such as the **Pinterest for iPhone**:

> https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token

You will see that the access_token is returned in the hash of the URL. You can now use this access_token to play with the endpoints and it is valid for one month. Have fun discovering them!

Endpoints that are public and do not require access_token:

**Pins with a known username and known board name:**

> https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/[username]/[board_name]/pins/

**Pins with a known username:**

> https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/[username]/pins/

**Retrieving the information of (a) particular pin(s):**

> http://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=521150988102375972,10133167885969245

**Count the number of pins:**

> http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=[urlEncodedLink]

Comment: Ben, nice tip on the oauth access token.

Comment: the only thing missing from these end points is the published date of the pin.

Comment: Are there any more public requests that don't need an access token?  The only other one I've found is pidgets/boards/highquality/pins

Comment: Isn't there a request limit? Will they block my IP if I search for too many boards?

Comment: Since yesterday they do not seem to allow the use of the access token generated by iphone app. Don't know what they changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get any of the endpoints listed to work (I've setup my server with an SSL; so the oAuth bit does pass back a proper access_key). however, this bit doesn't work: (I use https://)+ api.pinterest.com/v3/boards?#access_token=pinterest_generated_token (I get a 405: not allowed error)

Comment: @DotNet98 The ones listed here are the groups of endpoints that are available. Each group has a number of endpoints, such as https://api.pinterest.com/v3/boards/{numeric board id}/pins/?page_size=100&access_token={access token}

Comment: @BenWong, oh that's great to hear! is there a way to get just the list of All boards for a user though? that gives me the PINs; I need a way to get the boards for the user... thanks again for your reply... this is very helpful!

Comment: It seems the trick with access_token doesn't work, it returns "Authentication failed." even with access_token. Any ideas how to workaround this?

Comment: @CorbanBrook have you managed to find the published dates of the pins? Is there any way to get this info?

Comment: Count the number of pins: is not working

Comment: @BenWong So you posted this in 2014 and the official Pinterest API documentation still hasn't been updated with these V3 links. So which one should I use, V3 or V1 links?

Answer (score 13):

As of June 11, 2012 there is no officially released or documentation API for Pinterest. A [Pinterest support page](https://support.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api) has a link to a form to be notified when it is officially released.

Comment: I've filled out that Google docs form several times in the past year but Pinterest has not contacted me yet.

Comment: @DylanValade, same here. Looking forward to have an API. Now I just have to scrape html and parse it a bit. But there is no date to sort on or whatsoever

Comment: @JPHellemons Thanks for posting the v3 update

Comment: @JPHellemons did you ever find a way to make the date show up?

Comment: Nope, sorry I have no update

Answer (score 11):

Check [Pinterest API](http://pinterestapi.co.uk) for a scraper for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone's still interested, apparently URLs in the format

```
https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/{{ USER }}/pins
```

will return a nice payload of information, including user info.

Answer (score 3):

There's an unofficial Pinterest API in Mashape - https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/pinterest-1#!documentation

Screenshot below:

[image]

And here's another one that might be worth looking at (uses PhantomJSCloud API) - https://www.mashape.com/novaleaf/pinterest-to-json#!documentation

Sample response looks like this:

```
{
  "pinterest_parser": {
    "boards": [
      {
        "boardCover": {
          "alt": "Stuff We Love / by Etsy",
          "src": "http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/custom_covers/216x146/155303955839058075_1385935738.jpg"
        },
        "boardThumbs": [
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/45x45/eb/90/3d/eb903ddac82981f34f2071753ec2d9ac.jpg"
          },
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/45x45/01/54/79/015479f7d193838cab29334953416cf2.jpg"
          },
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/45x45/79/11/36/7911362bd2fb73a2b2edf8427e944c69.jpg"
          },
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/45x45/1b/a8/66/1ba866bdc7a4e4ee0d99fc838be1b2bb.jpg"
           }
        ],
        "href": "/etsy/products-i-love/",
        "pins": "690",
        "title": "Stuff We Love\n                            Etsy"
      },
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite old, but if anyone is still interested in an up-to-date answer: Pinterest has finally launched an [official API](https://dev.pinterest.com/), including an SDK for Javascript, Android and iOS.

I've been working on a [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP) for it and noticed that not every endpoint in the documentation is working properly, but most of the things are working.

Answer (score 2):

iv got a simple and quick way to post to Pinterest but unfortunately at this time it will only post a pin to a board and give the user the option to view their profile.

Im a iOS developer using Titanium Studio, build: 3.0.1.20.

```
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='ADD WEBSITE URL HERE '&media='ADD PICTURE URL HERE'&description=ADD DESCRIPTION HERE',
    top : offset,
    right : offset,
    bottom : offset,
    left : offset,
    autoDetect : [Ti.UI.iOS.AUTODETECT_NONE]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewFitzgerald I tested your url and it works properly.  This is the functionality of the Pin It button generator found here https://pinterest.com/about/goodies/#button_for_websites

Answer (score 2):

It seems that 
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pins/jphellemons/

gives this message:

```
{
    "status": "failure", 
    "code": 2, 
    "host": "ngapi-10430284",  
    "generated_at": "Wed, 26 Jun 2013 14:56:44 +0000", 
    "message": "Authentication failed.", 
    "data": null
}
```

and url https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pins/ gives

```
{
    "status": "failure", 
    "code": 5, 
    "host": "ngapi-70bcb1cc", 
    "generated_at": "Wed, 26 Jun 2013 15:01:07 +0000", 
    "message": "Method not allowed", 
    "data": "405 Method Not Allowed"
}
```

So the upcoming API will be at that url I guess. Just authenticate with oAuth I guess.
Because they hired John Yi recently

- http://allthingsd.com/20130612/the-pinterest-api-is-coming-head-of-marketing-developer-partnerships-joins-up/
- http://www.businessinsider.com/pinterest-hires-john-yi-to-launch-api-2013-6

if you cannot wait for the official api: http://pinterestapi.co.uk/

**update 18 june** http://readwrite.com/2013/06/18/the-disappointing-tale-of-pinterests-long-awaited-api#awesm=~oeF8IxscKLvPhN

**update 31 july** http://allthingsd.com/20130731/about-that-pinterest-api-its-not-ready-yet/

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation  for pinterest i found, And it helps may i hope it will help u also 
[Official documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/431430839282408407/?access_token=aaa
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/lorihiney/quotes/pins/?access_token=aa&limit=20&fields=id,link,counts
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/mother1086/test-title/pins/?access_token=aaa&limit=2&fields=id,link,counts
```