# Getting Pinterest followers count with jQuery or php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, counter, pinterest

I am looking for a way to display a text number in a div (#pinterest_count) of the Pinterest followers of a certain Pinterest account. Do you know an working solution (code example) written in jquery or php?

regards

Comment: you can get the number of followers in this way using PHP:
```<?php
$metas = get_meta_tags('http://pinterest.com/pinterest/');
print_r($metas['pinterestapp:followers']);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinterest are yet to release a public API, so at the moment you wont be able to do this.

see related question here: [pinterest api documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation)

Comment: thanks, i missed that topic when i made the research.

Comment: if you're really intent on getting and displaying the followers of an account you could go down the route of screen-scraping...not ideal, but a possibility (provided pinterest don't disallow it)