# Log in with Pinterest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, authentication, pinterest

I can easy implement log in with facebook on iPhone. But I heared, that there was no official API for pinterest.

So I wonder if there is a way to implement login with Pinterest. So my app can identify user after his login with pinterest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Without an official Pinterest public API](https://support.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api), anything else you write to be some kind of workaround is likely to break very easily. Best to register with Pintrist directly and hopefully they'll seed you with access to a beta SDK or API, once they come up with it.

That said, [there appears to be some stuff potentially available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation) but not sure what the current status is.

Answer (score 1):

Pintrest uses oAuth2 you should be able to use it akin of all the other providers  ie GET request to a certain url to obtain the token, step by step instructions can be found here 
http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api

OAuth2 is an official api the issue boils down to finding the endpoint and GET syntax 
One thing to note is the object that is being returned can contain different values accross providers for instance I needed a Twitter and FB solution, but Twitter doesn't give you user's email so you had to ask for it separately (to uniquely identify the same account accross providers) 
For ruby there's the omniauth gem that lets you use multiple providers (strategies) with ease. Shouldn't be to complicated to roll out your own solution for or find a library for IOS

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no official api for Pinterest, But  
 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation) is a link already answered

or try like this, create button with the following target
`[pintrestBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pintrestButtonSelcted) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`

and push when the `htmlstring` comes as perfect url push it to another viewcontroller which has webview and load this `htmlstring` in that webview

```
- (void) pintrestButtonSelcted {

NSString *htmlString = [self generatePinterestHTMLForSKU:nil];
NSLog(@"Generated HTML String:%@", htmlString);
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
webViewController.htmlString = htmlString;
webViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (NSString*) generatePinterestHTMLForSKU:(NSString*)sku {
NSString *description = @"Post your description here";

// Generate urls for button and image
NSString *sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://reedperry.com/2011/04/27/apple-logo/"];
NSLog(@"URL:%@", sUrl);
NSString *protectedUrl = ( NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,( CFStringRef)sUrl, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
NSLog(@"Protected URL:%@", protectedUrl);
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", sUrl];
NSString *buttonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinterest/id429047995?mt=8&media=http://reedperry.com/2011/04/27/apple-logo/%@&description=Welcome you all%@\"", protectedUrl, description];

NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><img width=\"400px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
return htmlString;
```

}

Comment: if you load it with webview, first it'll come `Pin it`, if you click that button, it'll redirect you to the `Login` page

Comment: I need to get login information (some kind of token) to identify user in my application