# How to check if a user is authorized in the Pinterest IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, pinterest

In my other app using Parse here I check if `currentUser` was nil, and if not segued past the `LogInViewController`.  With the Pinterest SDK I can't find anywhere in the documentation where I can check for a `currentUser`.

What's the best way to structure this so that if the user had authorized already, `performSegueWIthIdentifier`, if not display this `LogInViewController`?   I was thinking about saving the user's name to `NSUserDefaults` and then calling `PDClient.sharedInstance().getUser(nameSavedToNSUD)`, and if success perform the segue but it seemed like a bit of hack and there has to be a better way?

```
import UIKit

class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func didPressLogInButton(sender: UIButton) {


        let permission = [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,
            PDKClientWritePublicPermissions,
            PDKClientReadPrivatePermissions,
            PDKClientWritePrivatePermissions,
            PDKClientReadRelationshipsPermissions,
            PDKClientWriteRelationshipsPermissions]
        PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions(permission,
            withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in


                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showBoards", sender: self)



            }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                print("error NSError: \(err)")
        }





    }


}
```

Comment: Going through liitle bit more on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405708/login-with-pinterest-in-ios)

Comment: Thank you but this post was prior to the release of their new API I think, they do have log in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinterest SDK has a `silentlyAuthenticatedWithSuccess' method that works great here:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().silentlyAuthenticateWithSuccess( { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in


            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showBoards", sender: self)



            }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                print("error NSError: \(err)")
        }
```

Comment: This method works inconsistently. Sometimes, it is successful but sometimes failed. Do you experience the same ?

Comment: @KongHantrakool no I haven't had any problems in my experience