# How to properly integrate Pinterest in Android app?

Tags: android, pinterest

I am using the REST API for integrating Pinterest into my Android app, but I'm getting an error when attempting to access categories.

My code:

```
String url = "https://api.pinterest.com/";
String allCategories = "/v2/boards/categories/";
RestClient client = new RestClient(url + allCategories);
String response = "";

    try {
        client.AddParam("limit", "36");

        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response = client.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(">>> Exception >>> " + e + " >>> Message >>> "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(">>> response >>> " + response);
    Log.d(">> Login response >>> ", response);
```

I'm getting the following error returned from the endpoint:

```
{
    "message": "Please upgrade your app!", 
    "error": "Authentication failed: Please upgrade your app!"
}
```

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/pinterest-api-programming) and see how to use Pinterest API Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

`Pinterest` doesn't have any official api, and it's unofficial api is [not working now](http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api). So I don't think your code will work any way, unless someone finds any other unofficial api or Pinterest releases the official version.

PS: [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation).

Comment: Just check the url - https://api.pinterest.com/v2/boards/categories/ it'll print the same error message you're getting.

Comment: Official answer from pinterest - https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api

Answer (score -1):

As of today, pinterest API has been taken down
(look [here](https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api))

In the meantime you might want to use this 3rd party implemented scraper, which works just like an API

http://pinterestapi.co.uk/

You can use this to get the boards, likes and pins of a user.

Note: Curiously the count for the v1 api still [works](http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=http://twitter.com). But again this is undocumented behaviour and dont rely on this