# Official Pinterest API Documentation

Tags: c#

Is there official documentation on the Pinterest API?

I want to integrate share Pintrest option in my website.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation) question. It lists various links that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful :)

[Pintrest developers page](http://developers.pinterest.com/)