# Pinterest API Access token expire

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, pinterest

My question is does Pinterest access token expires?

I am obtaining access token following Pinterest official documentation:

For getting authorization code:

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/#getting-your-authorization-code

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?
    response_type=code&
    redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/connect/pinterest/&
    client_id=12345&
    scope=read_public,write_public&
    state=768uyFys
```

And for getting access token:

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/#getting-your-access-token

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?
    grant_type=authorization_code&
    client_id=12345&
    client_secret=6789abcd&
    code=xyz1010
```

The actual response is:

```
{
    "access_token": "AfISUq75NELGEECEurmvEcIwlQZDFFBOnAdsa", 
    "token_type": "bearer", 
    "scope": [
        "read_public", 
        "write_public", 
        "read_private", 
        "write_private", 
        "read_write_all"
        ]
}
```

Nothing I can find in Pinterest documentation about token expire, and expiration date is not returned in response.

As per this question [Pinterest returns expired token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24321982/3654631)

i can see that this guy is using API v3 endpoint:
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/code_exchange/

and in response he is getting `expires_at` field

In pinterest documentation I cannot find anything about API versinos V2 or V3,

all their documentation [Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/) is about API V1.

Any help about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pinterest access token appears to have no expiry date, at least in the current version of the API.  From the [documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/):

> Exchange for an access token. Your app will call the API to exchange the authorization code for an access token, **which is a permanent credential** (unless the user revokes your access). You'll use the access token to perform actions on Pinterest on your user's behalf.

I happen to know the Stack Overflow OAuth token also has no expiry date, in case you were wondering whether any other major sites use this workflow.

Comment: thanks I don't know how I missed this in the documentation. Yeap, Twitter token also doesn't expire