# Pulling Data Counts from Instagram / Facebook / Twitter API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, instagram, pinterest

I'm new to writing code and I'd like to know if there's a way to get the total number of posts per hashtag from Instagram / Facebook / Twitter / Pinterest.

For instance, If a picture is tagged with the #fun on

Instagram with 4000 photos
Facebook with 2000 posts
Twitter with 2000 posts
Pinterest with 20000 pins,

I would like to pull the numbers 4000, 2000, 2000 and 20000 from these above mentioned APIs. Is this possible? Any links or tutorials to this would be helpful!

Thanks
Vila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Facebook, there's the Hashtag Counter API (you have to apply for this API before you can use it):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/hashtag_counter/v2.1

Twitter has no direct API for that, so you'll have to count the search results:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/building-twitter-hashtag-contest-creating-counting-tweets/

For Instagram, you can use the `/tags/{tag_name}` endpoint:

- http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags

Pinterest doesn't have an "official" API for this use case. There are some insights at

- [pinterest api documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation)