# Pinterest Api limit the number of pins returned

Tags: api, pinterest

using this request to get the pins of a user for Pinterest Api(from [pinterest api documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation))

> http://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/{username}/pins/

but by default returns a array of 50 pins is there a way to limit to lower number of pins returned?

Comment: Such option doesn't seem to be available. Why do you need to limit? You can just get the results and drop the overhead in post-processing.

Comment: thats what I am doing but would prefer to limit from the start to speed up the process since this one of multiple Api's that I am using to retrive information of a user posts and in all the other Api's was able at least to limit the rows return and in same cases also the fields that were returned.

Answer (score 1):

Go here, click ***Generate***, and get an access token: https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/

Get the statuses using ***note&limit=int***: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=id,creator,note&limit=2

See docs for extra parameters: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/